# How does MPI_IN_PLACE work with MPI_Scatter?

Tags: c, mpi, distributed-computing

What exactly does `MPI_IN_PLACE` do when given as an argument to `MPI_Scatter` and how should it be used? I can't make sense of `man MPI_Scatter`:

> When the communicator is an intracommunicator, you can perform a gather operation in-place (the output buffer is used as the input buffer).  Use the  variable MPI_IN_PLACE as the value of the root process recvbuf.  In this case, recvcount and recvtype are ignored, and the root process sends no data to itself. Because the in-place option converts the receive buffer into a send-and-receive buffer, a Fortran binding that includes INTENT must mark these as INOUT, not OUT.

What I want to do is use the same buffer that contains the data on the root as the receive buffer at each other process (like in `MPI_Bcast`). Will `MPI_Scatter` with `MPI_IN_PLACE` let me do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sendbuf of MPI_scatter is only relevant on the root according to [mpich](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Scatter.html),

> sendbuf -- 
>   address of send buffer (choice, significant only at root)

From [this](http://lists.mcs.anl.gov/pipermail/mpich-discuss/2010-April/007069.html) discussion,

> For scatter/scatterv, MPI_IN_PLACE should be passed as the recvbuf. For  gather and most other collectives, MPI_IN_PLACE should passed as the sendbuf.

You therefore need to use MPI_IN_PLACE in the recv buffer location on the root process, e.g.

```
if (rank == iroot)
     MPI_Scatter(buf, sendcount, MPI_Datatype, MPI_IN_PLACE, sendcount,  
                 MPI_Datatype, iroot, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
else
     MPI_Scatter(dummy, sendcount, MPI_Datatype, buf, sendcount, MPI_Datatype,  
                 iroot, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

You could then use `buf` in the send on root and the same `buf` in the recv position on each other process. The `dummy` buffer on the receiving processors could probably also be replaced by `MPI_IN_PLACE`.

Comment: The dummy buffer could be replaced by `NULL` as it is never read from.

Comment: The dummy buffer could be replaced by `NULL` as it is never read from in a conforming implementation ;-)