# How to do an MPI_Scatter in MPI to all nodes except the root?

Tags: mpi, distributed-computing, hpc

In MPI, if I perform an MPI_Scatter on MPI_COMM_WORLD, all the nodes receive some data (including the sending root).

How do I perform an MPI_Scatter from a root node to all the other nodes and **make sure the root node does not receive any data**?

Is creating a new MPI_Comm containing all the nodes but the root a viable approach?

Comment: No creating another communicator isn't a viable option. Using `MPI_IN_PLACE` is however.

Comment: You may also use `MPI_Scatterv` and set the block length for the root rank equal to zero.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does MPI\_IN\_PLACE work with MPI\_Scatter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29415663/how-does-mpi-in-place-work-with-mpi-scatter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's imagine your code looks like that:

```cpp
int rank, size;    // rank of the process and size of the communicator
int root = 0;      // root process of our scatter
int recvCount = 4; // or whatever
double *sendBuf = rank == root ? new double[recvCount * size] : NULL;
double *recvBuf = new double[recvCount];

MPI_Scatter( sendBuf, recvCount, MPI_DOUBLE,
             recvBuf, recvCount, MPI_DOUBLE,
             root, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
```

So in here, indeed, the `root` process will send data to itself although this could be avoided.
Here are the two obvious methods that come to mind to achieve that.

**Using `MPI_IN_PLACE`**
The call to `MPI_Scatter()` wouldn't have to change. The only change in the code would be for the definition of the receiving buffer, which would become something like this:

```cpp
double *recvBuf = rank == root ?
                  static_cast<double*>( MPI_IN_PLACE ) :
                  new double[recvCount];
```

**Using `MPI_Scatterv()`**
With that, you'd have to define an array of integers describing the individual receiving sizes, an array of displacements describing the starting indexes and use them in a call to `MPI_Scatterv()` which would replace you call to `MPI_Scatter()` like this:

```cpp
int sendCounts[size] = {recvCount};  // everybody receives recvCount data
sendCounts[root] = 0;                // but the root process
int displs[size];
for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
    displs[i] = i * recvCount;
}

MPI_Scatterv( sendBuf, sendCounts, displs, MPI_DOUBLE,
              recvBuf, recvCount, MPI_DOUBLE,
              root, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
```

Of course in both cases no data would be on receiving buffer for process `root` and this would have to be accounted for in your code.

I personally prefer the first option, but both work.