# How to use MPI_Scatter to split data to all other processes except the root?

Tags: c, mpi

Assume we have 4 process (rank 0 - rank 3), and rank 0 has the data = `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`. What I wanna do is

from:

rank 0: `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, rank 1: `[]`, rank 2: `[]`, rank 3: `[]`

to :

rank 0: `[]`, rank 1: `[1,2]`, rank 2: `[3,4]`, rank 3: `[5,6]`

basically, rank 0 dispatches data to all others and rank 0 will not be assigned data. I realise there is similar question that can be addressed with `MPI_IN_PLACE`. I tried but didn't get what I want.

[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43107963/how-to-do-an-mpi-scatter-in-mpi-to-all-nodes-except-the-root)

Comment: From a link in one of the related section, how about [MPI_Scatterv](http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.4/man3/MPI_Scatterv.3.php)

Comment: Compute the total length, divide by number or processes minus one, set up an all-to-all. Btw, this has nothing to do with `MPI_IN_PLACE`.

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks for your reply, I am wondering if there is elegant way than MPs_Scatterv

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Thank you Victor, it could be a solution, but I am still wondering if there is a more straightforward way. Such communication pattern is that Master dispatches data to Slave in Spark. So I think if I missed there is a simple way using MPI_Scatter in MPI.

Comment: An other option would be to create an intercommunicator with rank 0 in one group, and the other ranks in the other group. Then you can simply `MPI_Scatter()` (assuming the size of your array is a multiple of the number of non zero ranks).
One might see this as an elegant solutions, but others might see it as unnecessarily convoluted with no guarantee it would be faster than `MPI_Scatterv()`.

Comment: @Liang (Please don't use the terms M & S anymore. All style guides tell you at least to use the term Worker.) Ok, so how would a supervisor process dispatch something to a worker if they don't have it? This is distributed memory. There is no real supervisor that has all the data. Each process has its own data.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thanks for your suggestion. It seems `MPI_Scatterv()` is a good choice for this question.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Sorry for misusing M&S term. And thanks for your advise. But what if only manager process reads data and manager wants to distribute to all workers?

Comment: Use scatter or broadcast.